# Cumulative incidence or simple proportion?

Tags: proportion

I have a database of unique ICD-9/10 counts for herpes zoster and a subgroup of counts specifically for herpes zoster ophthalmicus codes split by year. If I wish to express the number of herpes zoster ophthalmicus cases out of all herpes zoster cases, can I call this cumulative incidence (incidence proportion, risk) or can I just call this a proportion? What exactly should I call it? In a sense those with herpes zoster are the at-risk population, but I am also just describing how many of this population happened to have disease around the eye. Thank you.